# Why doesn't XmlEncoder insert members of a class into an xml file?

Tags: java, xml-serialization

I'm trying to put into XML-file some data. Here is the code:

```
@Test
public void TestProximities() {

    // Create a proximity 
    ISpaceComponent solarSystem = Init.createSolarSystemProximities();
    solarSystem.runTtest();

    Path filePath = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\junk.bin");

    File xmlFile = new File("c:\\temp\\");
    boolean success = xmlFile.mkdirs();
    if (!success && ! xmlFile.exists() ) {
        // Directory creation failed
        System.out.println("Failed to create a file: " + filePath);
    }

    try {
        XMLEncoder fileXml = new XMLEncoder( new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\junk.xml") ) );
        fileXml.writeObject(solarSystem);
        fileXml.flush();
        fileXml.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

Init.createSolarSystemProximities():

```
public static ISpaceComposite createSolarSystemProximities() {

    // Proximities
    ISpaceComposite solarSystem = new SpaceComposite("The Solar System");
    solarSystem.addComponent(new Star("Sol"));      

    ISpaceComposite MercuryProximity = new SpaceComposite("Mercury proximity");
    MercuryProximity.addComponent(new Planet("Mercury"));
    solarSystem.addComponent(MercuryProximity);

    ISpaceComposite VenusProximity = new SpaceComposite("Venus proximity");
    VenusProximity.addComponent(new Planet("Venus"));
    solarSystem.addComponent(VenusProximity);

    ISpaceComposite EarthProximity = new SpaceComposite("Earth proximity");
    EarthProximity.addComponent(new Planet("The Earth"));
    EarthProximity.addComponent(new Moon("The Moon"));
    solarSystem.addComponent(EarthProximity);

    ISpaceComposite MarsProximity = new SpaceComposite("Mars proximity");
    MarsProximity.addComponent(new Planet("Mars"));
    MarsProximity.addComponent(new Moon("Phobos"));
    MarsProximity.addComponent(new Moon("Deimos"));
    solarSystem.addComponent(MarsProximity);

    return solarSystem;

}
```

And the space composite class is looking like this:

```
public class SpaceComposite extends SpaceComponent implements ISpaceComposite {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = Data.serialVersionUID;
    private ArrayList<ISpaceComponent> _components;
private int _currentMoonIndex;

}
```

Also 'SpaceComposite' has default prameterless constructor. But the only thing, which is inserted into a file, is its name, derrived from the 'SpaceComponent' class

```
public abstract class SpaceComponent implements ISpaceComponent, Serializable{
    private String _title;
    public static final long serialVersionUID = Data.serialVersionUID;

    // Default constructor
    public SpaceComponent(){
        _title = "";
    }
 }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XmlEncoder`](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence4/) captures properties using JavaBean conventions. It works by cloning the object graph and recording the steps that were necessary to create the clone. A class that you would like to use with XmlEncoder without any customizations needs to follow JavaBeans conventions (`getXYZ/setXYZ` for properties or `isAbc/setAbc` for boolean properties, etc.) My guess is that the only property available like that in your class is `Name`, hence it's the only one being serialized.

The article at the link also explains how you can customize the process by providing your own persistence delegate, but I would try adding getters/setters first to see if that is enough to make it work.

Comment: Can I declare some setters with private access modificator? I need it  because i don't want to get full access to the private members for a third-party code

Comment: @Eugene To tell you the truth, I do not have much experience with `XMLEncoder`, but I would definitely try using private or package visibility for my setters that I do not want exposed to the outside world.